# sequelize.query returns unrelated number

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

Below is my table creation command

```
create table person ( pid INT primary key, pname varchar(50), page int , psalary int, paddress varchar(50) , paddresstwo varchar(50) , pregnum(50))
```

This is my stored procedure

```
create procedure personsalcheck
@searchsal int,
@outsal varchar(50)   output
as
begin
declare @num varchar(50)
set @num = 'This is date ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 105)
select * from person where psalary > @searchsal
set  @outsal = @num 

end
```

And this is my command

```
DECLARE  @value varchar(50) 
 EXEC   personocheckout    @searchsal = 56000,  
  @outsal = @value OUTPUT  
select @value as Result
```

When I ran this command in sequelize.query in nodejs then the below output was generated

```
 [
  [
    {
      pid: 2,
      pname: 'Jane Smith',
      page: 32,
      psalary: 60000,
      paddress: '456 Elm St',
      paddresstwo: null,
      pregnum: null
    },
    {
      pid: 3,
      pname: 'Bob Johnson',
      page: 45,
      psalary: 75000,
      paddress: '789 Oak St',
      paddresstwo: null,
      pregnum: null
    },
    {
      pid: 5,
      pname: 'David Kim',
      page: 38,
      psalary: 65000,
      paddress: '654 Pine St',
      paddresstwo: null,
      pregnum: null
    },
    {
      pid: 6,
      pname: 'Lisa Chen',
      page: 42,
      psalary: 70000,
      paddress: '987 Cedar Ln',
      paddresstwo: null,
      pregnum: null
    },
    {
      pid: 7,
      pname: 'Tom Brown',
      page: 33,
      psalary: 60000,
      paddress: '246 Oak Ln',
      paddresstwo: null,
      pregnum: null
    },
    {
      pid: 9,
      pname: 'Mike Johnson',
      page: 40,
      psalary: 80000,
      paddress: '864 Maple St',
      paddresstwo: null,
      pregnum: null
    },
    {
      pid: 10,
      pname: 'Julia Lee',
      page: 30,
      psalary: 65000,
      paddress: '975 Pine Ave',
      paddresstwo: null,
      pregnum: null
    },
    {
      pid: 11,
      pname: 'Jack Kim',
      page: 35,
      psalary: 70000,
      paddress: '246 Cedar St',
      paddresstwo: null,
      pregnum: null
    },
    {
      pid: 13,
      pname: 'Chris Brown',
      page: 31,
      psalary: 60000,
      paddress: '468 Elm St',
      paddresstwo: null,
      pregnum: null
    },
    { Result: 'This is date 09-05-2023' }
  ],
  12
]
```

Now I am able to understand the entire output and it is even matching with the output shown in SQL management studio.However I am unable to understand what `12` means or why it has been returned. Earlier I thought that it is equal to the number of records returned by here , we have only 9 records and 1 output , so why 12 is showing.

Comment: Please show the whole Sequelize command

Comment: does running: SET NOCOUNT ON; at the start of procedure make any diff?

Comment: Using output parameters is a decidedly non-ORM thing to do which is why it's not generally supported by ORMs like Sequelize. Consider either returning what's currently your output parameter as an extra column in the main result set (which then requires a custom model to receive it in a new property), or for custom queries like this bypass Sequelize altogether and use `mssql` (which Sequelize wraps for SQL Server databases) with [Prepared Statements and output parameters](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#output-name-type).